# Conditional Gitignore

Tags: git, emacs, versioning, org-mode, gitignore

I have a git repo in which I store my personal documents. Some of these documents are LaTeX files and some even are PDFs. I of course want them to be in my documents repo.

But when I create an org-mode document (`*.org`), I often build it, resulting in these files being created if the org-mode document is called `α`:

- α.tex
- α.pdf
- auto/α.el

I don't want to track them as they are generated files of which I have the source code but I can't simply ignore all `*.tex` and not even all `*.pdf` files.

Can a `.gitignore` be told to ignore every file whose name is `α.tex` or `α.pdf` if there is a file called `α.org` with `α` being a variable for an arbitrary string?

Comment: Instead of ignoring those files maybe it would be easier to simply remove them: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23982/cleanup-org-mode-export-intermediary-file

Comment: build those files inside a folder that will be ignored in your gitignore file.

Comment: @Jules Doesn't work. That method gets rid of the `*.tex` file and can get rid of the `*.pdf` file but I want to use the latter. Furthermore, that method can't remove the `*.el` file, probably because it's in a different directory. I can see how a solution on Emac's side is possible, though: If it was possible to build the files to a directory with a specific name (doesn't matter whether it's the same directory for all files no matte their location or whether it's in the location of the `*.org` file, it only has to have a specific name), that'd solve the problem.

Comment: @Nsukami_ Is this possible?

Comment: You can tell gitignore to ignore a whole folder, so if the generated files are under the ignored folder, your problem should be solved. You should tell your build command to put the generated file somewhere, for example build/ folder. Then, add build/ inside .gitignore. That's it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible, `.gitignore` is quite simple file and doesn't allow any conditional rules.

However, generally good idea is to prepare the build system to generate all the intermediate files into some build directory. Often is used `build` or `target`. Then you could simply put into `.gitignore`:

```
/target # / specifies the root path
/auto # probably your temporary files...?
```

If the compiling is done with Makefile, the rules can look like:

```
target/%.pdf: target/%.tex
         $(LATEX) -o $@ $<
target/%.tex: %.org
         generate_tex -o $@ $<
```

(not sure so much about syntax for latex and of course the specific command for generating `*.tex` from `*.org`)